# $a->b = new cl(); How to call $a->x() from within $a->b->c() without having to pass $a as an argument to c();

Tags: php, methods, call, siblings

PHP

```
class ClA {

    var $b;

    function clA()
    {
        $this->b = new ClB();
    }

    function x()
    {
      echo "testing";
    }
}        


class ClB {

    function clB()
    {

    }

    function c ($a)
    {
       $a->x();
    }
}

$a = new ClA();

$a->b->c($a);
```

How to call c() without having to pass $a;

Calling a method that is a member 
of an object that is one level up 
to the current object 
whose method is being called.

```
function c ()
{
   ??->x();
}
```

?? => object One Level Up To Current Object Of which This Method Is A Member

Comment: @Rizier123 - Nope, `b` is a property

Comment: @MarkBaker Definitely too late for me today.

Comment: well this would be such a joy to maintain

Answer (score 4):

```
class ClA {

    public $b;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->b = new ClB($this);
    }

    public function x() {
      echo "testing";
    }
}        


class ClB {

    private $a;

    public function __construct($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function c () {
       $this->a->x();
    }
}

$a = new ClA();

$a->b->c();
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/j0aLe8)

Note that I've updated your classes to PHP5 from PHP4

Comment: I was trying to find out if there is any way I can avoid passing $a at any stage by addressing it as "object One Level Up To Current Object Of which This Method Is A Member".

Comment: Then the anwer is "No". Variables have no understanding of anything beyond their immediate scope; especially as there could conceivably be several instances of "object One Level Up To Current Object Of which This Method Is A Member".

Comment: Don't properties have such an understanding?  Would this ambiguity on account of the multiple instances of "object one level up to current object"  be a factor in  cases where the objective is accessing methods only, say when the code within the method is not in any way dependent on the object?